# Modify rewrite rule to match ONLY directories, NOT directories AND files

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, regex

I have the following rule in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/].*/(dir1|dir2|dir3)(.+) $1$2 [QSA]
```

It works great for the directories except sometimes it conflicts with *files*.

How can I modify this rule to immediately require a `/` after each directory name so that it only matches directories and not files?

Here are some of the things I've tried without success:

1. `RewriteRule ^[^/].*/(dir1|dir2\/|dir3)(.+) $1$2 [QSA]`
2. `RewriteRule ^[^/].*/(dir1|dir2|dir3)(\/(.+) $1$2 [QSA]`
3. `RewriteRule ^[^/].*/(dir1|dir2|dir3)(\/.+) $1$2 [QSA]`

Example: `im/` should match however `immortal.woff2` should not.

Comment: Please update your question with examples of URLs that should match and URLs that should not (which you are having issues with). What are you expecting that rule to accomplish? What other rules do you have and in what order? There are a number of potential issues with that rule, but we need more info to be able to answer this properly.

Comment: Not my strong suite, but could you not just prefix these rules with **RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d**

Comment: @davidgo The OP doesn't appear to be literally matching directories only, but rather files in a set of known directories (and including the directory itself), but avoiding files that happen to have one of the known directory names as a prefix. eg. It would match `foo/im/` or `foo/im/file.ext`, but not `foo/immortal.woff2`. (However, making the regex more restrictive is preferable to implementing an additional file system check - the original regex is basically just missing a slash, ie. `(/.*)` instead of `(.+)`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 3. `RewriteRule ^[^/].*/(dir1|dir2|dir3)(\/.+) $1$2 [QSA]`

This would potentially do as you require, however, this does not match your example `im/` (or rather `<something>/im/` where `im` is one of `dir1`, `dir2`, or `dir3`), it would only match `<something>/im/<something>` due to the `+` (1 or more) quantifier in the last capturing subgroup. To match `<something>/im/` you should change the last quantifier to `*` (0 or more) instead.

Other (not so) minor points...

- You do not need to backslash-escape literal slashes in Apache regex since *spaces* are the regex delimiters, so slashes carry no special meaning here.
- The `QSA` flag is not required here, since the query string is passed through by default (when a query string is omitted from the *substitution* string).
- The first part of the regex, ie. `^[^/].*/`, looks incorrect. This matches a non-slash character, followed by anything (including other slashes), followed by a slash. However, in a *directory* context (like `.htaccess`) the first character is never a slash, so the `[^/]` part is redundant. However, it looks like the dot is erroneous. It looks like the intention is to match a single path segment, eg. `foo/dir1/`, but the current regex would also match `foo/bar/baz/dir1/` - potentially creating a duplicate content issue (since the resulting rewrite is the same). To match a single path segment only then the first part of the regex should be `^[^/]+/` instead. Note the `+` (1 or more) quantifier applies to the non-slash character class. I used `+` as opposed to `*` since there will always be at least 1 character before the slash (as mentioned above, the first character is never a slash). This is of course assuming the `RewriteRule` directive is being applied to the requested URL and not the output of an earlier rewrite.
- You have omitted the `L` flag - are you performing additional rewrites on the output of this rule? Otherwise, the `L` flag should be included, at the very least to prevent additional (unnecessary) processing, or to prevent undesirable rewrites/redirects.

Bringing the above points together, try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(dir1|dir2|dir3)(/.*) $1$2 [L]
```

The purpose of this rule being to remove the first URL-path segment before a selection of known directories (or path segments) via an internal rewrite.

Comment: Great! This `RewriteRule` is used on `localhost` where the root folder is a Version of the software hence `^[^/]+`. The fix allows a font to load as it should (`immortal.woff2`) while allowing rewrite to a `im/` path. There are other rules yeah though in my experience posting code not directly related ends up leading people away from the answer I'm seeking. Thank you!